# What is the fastest, most correct way to solve this simultaneous of two linears?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

\begin{eqnarray*} (x+2)/5-((y+2)/4) &=& 2-(x/3) \\
(x+5)/4+((x-y)/5) &=& y+5 \end{eqnarray*}

What is the fastest, most correct way to solve this simultaneous of two linears?

Comment: Clear the denominators (don't forget to distribute), gather like terms, then solve for one variable, and then the other. Finally, check your solution(s) in both equations.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $LCD_1 = 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 = 60, LCD_2 = 4\cdot 5 = 20$. Multiply the first equation by $LCD_1 = 60$, and the second by $LCD_2 = 20$. Then simplify both equations each to the form: $ax+by = c$, then finally use elimination to get rid of either variable.

Comment: [code] I) 3x = 8y + 25 II) 32x = 15y + 126[/code]

Comment: move $8y$, and $15y$ to the left each.

Comment: Now what? It doesn't look right